# Please make sure that the argument SiteRepository at index [1] is available in the SitesModule context

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Im trying to implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typeorm-paginate

My service is as follows:

```js
import {Model} from 'mongoose';
import {Site, SiteDocument} from "./site.entity";
import {paginate, Pagination, IPaginationOptions} from "nestjs-typeorm-paginate";
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class SitesService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Site.name) private readonly siteModel: Model<SiteDocument>,
        @InjectRepository(Site) private readonly repository: Repository<SiteDocument>,
    ) {}

    //Get all Sites
    async getSites(options: IPaginationOptions): Promise<Pagination<SiteDocument>> {
        return paginate<SiteDocument>(this.repository, options);
    }
```

My controller

```js
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @Get('get')
    async index(
        @Query('page', new DefaultValuePipe(1), ParseIntPipe) page: number = 1,
        @Query('limit', new DefaultValuePipe(10), ParseIntPipe) limit: number = 10,
    ): Promise<Pagination<Site>> {
        limit = limit > 100 ? 100 : limit;
        return this.siteService.getSites({
            page,
            limit,
            route: 'http://cats.com/cats',
        });
    }
```

and my entity

```js
import {Document} from "mongoose";

export type SiteDocument = Site & Document;

@Schema()
export class Site{
    @Prop({required: true})
    name: string;
    @Prop()
    site_id: string;
    @Prop()
    properties: number;
     @Prop()
    area: string;
    @Prop()
    address_1: string;
    @Prop()
    address_2: string;
    @Prop()
    address_3: string;
    @Prop()
    postcode: string;
    @Prop()
    site_contact_name: string;
    @Prop()
    site_contact_phone: string;
    @Prop()
    site_contact_email: string;
    @Prop()
    google: string;
    @Prop()
    matterport: string;
    @Prop()
    surveyor: string;
    @Prop()
    survey_date: string;
    @Prop()
    presented: string;
}

export const SiteSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Site);
```

Sites Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {SiteSchema} from "./site.entity";
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { SitesController } from './sites.controller';
import { SitesService } from './sites.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Site', schema: SiteSchema}])
    ],
    providers: [SitesService],
    controllers: [SitesController]
})
export class SitesModule {}
```

I have tried using Site, SiteDocument and SiteSchema in the inject repository but I get the below error

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SitesService (SiteModel, ?). Please make sure that the argument SiteRepository at index [1] is available in the SitesModule context.

```
Potential solutions:
- Is SitesModule a valid NestJS module?
- If SiteRepository is a provider, is it part of the current SitesModule?
- If SiteRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within SitesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing SiteRepository */ ]
  })
```

Comment: show us the relevant part: the module `SitesModule`

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: Why are you using a TypeORM package when you use the `MongooseModule`?